# Create a table with fixed-width columns and variable width column

Tags: html, css, html-table

I want to create a table with 3 columns: On the left and right fixed-width columns (which are obscured by position:fixed - divs) and in the middle a variable width column.

This does NOT work:

```
<table>
    <tr>
        <td width=202px></td>
        <td> [MYCONTENT] </td>
        <td width=200px></td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

The problem is, that for some reason the browsers (tested on Chrome and Firefox) think that I don't really mean it when the browser-window is not wide enough: The outer columns are cropped and width-setting ignored, therefore the real content is sliding under my  divs and become completely inaccessible.

The only idea I have left is to use a 1990's-era transparent pixel resized to 200px width, but I shudder at the thought. There must surely be a better way?

(BTW, yes I have tried various pure-css layouts, and none was suitable, for example if you use overflow:auto for the middle column, the scrollbar at the bottom also scrolls(!!) that means if the page is both higher and wider than the window, you have to first scroll down to see the scrollbar, then scroll horizontally, then maybe scroll up again to see what you wanted to see in the first place. I also tried to use padding: to force the needed margins on the left and right, but this also was ignored when the browser-window was not wide enough.)

Comment: is this what you're trying to do? http://jsfiddle.net/m7q3H/167/

Comment: No, I want to *avoid* overlapping and use the global scrollbars when neccessary.

Comment: if you want to avoid overlapping then you need to set a container and use `position: absolute;` instead of `position: fixed;` and set a minimum width like this: http://jsfiddle.net/m7q3H/169/

Comment: Yes, that looks quite good, (margin instead of padding for the center column), thanks!

Comment: Just tried it, it works in the jsfiddle box, but does not work in a browser-window (when the window is too narrow, the left side is OK, but the right side overlaps and becomes unaccessable.)

Comment: there is going to be a point when you make your browser window small enough that your columns ( 200px x2 =400px )  have nowhere to go... and then crush your middle main-content thing... there are a lot of nuances when it comes to padding and margin - that is why you are getting that horizontal scrolling that you mentioned.. I would sugest maybe using a media query when your window gets to a certain size and either making your columns and content change size or position. I know you aren't looking for css. but take a look at this. (you can spend 30seconds) http://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/GBtdy/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok - here it is with tables.

http://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/wAGKp/2/

i guess the short answer would be -

- take the styles out of the html and use a selector.  (class in this case"  and then min-width --- and width...
- also - keep in mind that padding and margins will change the width of your stuff... so you could use the border-box method... (it's rad)  and included in the second... makes it so that padding stays in the original div size --- hope this helps.

and here it is the way i would do it.  (without tables...)

http://jsfiddle.net/sheriffderek/GBtdy/1/

Comment: p.s.      vertical-align: top;   (looks like it's middle by default...)

Answer (score 1):

Tables are for tabular data, if you want to layout content you should be using CSS.

I recommend using something like [Twitter Boostrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/) if you struggling with the CSS.

If you really just want a specific solution have a look at the results for terms like ["css 3 column layout fluid center](http://www.google.co.uk/#hl=en&q=css+3+column+layout+fluid+center&sa=X&ei=OuU0UJK6MIGH0AWN7YCoBg&ved=0CE8Q7xYoAA&bav=on.2,or.r_gc.r_pw.r_qf.&fp=1eacde5ba99084b&biw=1394&bih=907) - I am not fobbing you off with that, there really are great answers there that are exactly what you want, and lots of search results will take you to those pages (especially to the manisheriar.com and A List Apart articles).

You can use min-width (on the middle div) and max-width - as well as media queries - to help control what happens in smaller windows.

Comment: I wanted to avoid these unhelpful postings with my last paragraph... I did try css and it just *wants* to overlap and does *not want* to use the global scrollbars.

Comment: It's not debatable that tables for layout is the wrong solution. This is a solved problem that you can numerous answers for on Google.

Comment: Well, I didn't find anything on Google and neither you nor CKKiller and sheriffderek could come up with a CSS-based design that actually does what I need. Maybe there is a pure CSS-solution, but if there is, it surely is not trivial.

Comment: huh - i guess i don't know what you really needed.  I thought both of my fiddles accomplished it - but i guess i was always confused by the obscured thing.  throw a min width on the middle?  the only thing i have ever used a table for is to design a craiglist ad - since then only allow about 6 tags... --- good luck !!! let us know if something clicks -

Comment: Update: Have just edited the answer. There are many ways of doing it (using margin, or padding, or 3 divs) depending on the actual content you want to display, but it's pretty well covered online. Except for HTML email formatting, I've not had to use tables for layout since MSIE 5 (which was 12-13 years ago)!

Comment: Comment on update: I just tried the first Google result (http://www.manisheriar.com/holygrail/index.htm) and lo and behold- it may be "proper CSS", but it's unuasable because OF COURSE it does overlap when the window is too narrow (It even overlaps in a very ugly way, try it!).  Pure CSS-designs just don't work well with variable widths and heights. CSS overlaps by default, even though overlapping is hardly ever needed or wanted. With tables I have pretty much a guarantee that the cells will not overlap, with CSS-divs I usually have to jump through hoops to achieve it - if it can be achieved.

Comment: @Robby75 You just totally ignored what I said about min-width and max-width and media queries.